# Cannot assign date using GetDateTime method of IDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

the following statement at the end of my binder method throws an error:

```
return reader.GetDateTime(ordinal);
```

Reader is an instance of IDataReader.
In the debugger I've found that the value of ordinal is 1 and that reader[1] has a value of "12/31/9999"

The error being thrown is "Specified cast is not valid"

What's the issue here? Why can't this be converted to a DateTime object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `reader.GetValue(1).GetType().Name;`  It's most likely your database type is a String, not a DateTime.

You can try `DateTime.Parse(reader.GetValue(1).ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

> reader[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a value of "12/31/9999"

With the quotes?  That is, is the data type a string or character type of some kind?  According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the underlying data type needs to be a DateTime:

> No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a DateTime object.

If that's the case, you need to get the value as a string and convert it yourself.  Maybe something like:

```
var date = reader.GetString(ordinal);
var result = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime.TryParse(date, out result);
return result;
```

Comment: If you're using TryParse, you should be checking if it succeeded.  if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out result)) return result else throw new Exception("Invalid DateTime");

Comment: @Mangist: Maybe, maybe not.  Depends on the business logic.  In my example I use `DateTime.MinValue` as a default.  If that's not acceptable, the OP can certainly change that.  But there's currently no stated *requirement* that an exception must be thrown.  Indeed, if an un-parsable value is something that can be expected then throwing an exception is using exceptions for logic flow, which is very much an anti-pattern.

Comment: Your answers not wrong, it's just not using the Framework method correctly.  Exceptions were designed for exactly this purpose, and they create more robust code.  Checking for DateTime.MinValue is hokey in my opinion.  Each to their own I guess.

Comment: @Mangist: And using exceptions for logic flow is "hokey" in my opinion.  (As well as many, many others'.)  The framework method is being used correctly for exactly the intended purpose... Trying to parse a date and ignoring the `out` parameter if it fails.  What to do in the event of an unparseable date is business logic, the framework doesn't handle custom business logic for the developer.